# Flipclock on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, flipclock

I am trying to implement [Flipclock 24-hours](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/twenty-four-hour-clock) into my Ionic 2 application. I'm not sure if this could work as the [js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flipclock) is compatible with Ionic 2 in typescript. Hope anyone could enlighten me as I couldn't find any source about Flipclock in Ionic 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the docs to add third party libraries to ionic.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/

But you can start with:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
npm install flipclock --save
```

Then create a component to hold this logic and use it, to make the FlipClock lib work you will need the `ElementRef`, because the plugin needs the `HTMLElement` to create the clock.

So you will have something like this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery'

@Component({
   selector: 'my-clock',
   template: ''
})
export class MyClockComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      // If you have TS issues here add a cast like (<any>$(this.elementRef).FlipClock
      $(this.elementRef).FlipClock({
        clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'
    });
   }
}
```

That should do the work.

**Update**:

Add a custom copy config to be sure that your third party lib will be available in runtime.

- Create a `config` folder in the project.
- Create a file inside of
  the `config` folder named `copy.config.js`.

Add this to your `copy.config.js` file:

```
// this is a custom dictionary to make it easy to extend/override
// provide a name for an entry, it can be anything such as 'copyAssets' or 'copyFonts'
// then provide an object with a `src` array of globs and a `dest` string
module.exports = {
  copyAssets: {
    src: ['{{SRC}}/assets/**/*'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets'
  },
  copyIndexContent: {
    src: ['{{SRC}}/index.html', '{{SRC}}/manifest.json', '{{SRC}}/service-worker.js'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}'
  },
  copyFonts: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*', '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
  },
  copyPolyfills: {
    src: [`{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/${process.env.IONIC_POLYFILL_FILE_NAME}`,
          `{{ROOT}}/node_modules/flipclock/compiled/flipclock.min.js`],
    dest: '{{BUILD}}'
  },
  copySwToolbox: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js'],
    dest: '{{BUILD}}'
  }
}
```

In your `package.json` add this:

```
"config": {
   "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
}
```

Then add the `flipclock.min.js` script to your `index.html` file (after your build/main.js script):

```
<script src="build/flipclock.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that ionic is not able to detect any module named 'FlipClock', hence error is prompted at .FlipClock. The step for importing above is not working.

Comment: Try with `(<any>$(this.elementRef)).FlipClock` and tell me if that works.

Comment: I think <any> is equivalent to window. in Ionic 1? The syntax error went off and I get this error message:

``` Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "Flipclock" Error: Cannot find module "Flipclock" at Object.<anonymous> ```

Think the module went missing even after npm install.

Comment: Yes, I will update the answer to add JQuery and FlipClock to the build copy hook.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help. I think the the jQuery module has no issue. Only Flipclock has some import issue atm.